# How we can implement hashtag like feature using getstream

Tags: getstream-io

I want to create functionality similar to hashtags on Twitter with the Getstream.io API. Users will post messages to their own flat feeds with certain hashtags. Then I want to be able to filter all activities based on a certain hashtag.

Comment: I did not find anything in getstream documention.

Answer (score 9):

You have to think of a hashtag as a separate feed. Every hashtag is a topic feed with all activities posted with that specific identifier in their object. Thus to achieve this behavior with Getstream we need to create a feed group that can store feeds for all hashtags (or topics). Often such a feed group is called `topic` but you could also name it `hashtag` (create new feed groups on the [getstream.io dashboard](https://getstream.io/dashboard)). Now we need to be able to send activities to their corresponding topic feeds when posted to a users' flat feed. For this we can use the [to](http://getstream.io/docs/#targetting) field of activities. When a user posts an activity with hashtag `computers` in the message we will create the following activity on the users flat feed:

```
{
    "actor": "user:1",
    "object": "I love #computers ^^"
    "verb": "tweet",
    "to": ["topic:computers"]
}
```

The `to` field will make sure the activity is also added to the topic feed and distributed to all the followers of this topic feed.